# Excel lookup across multiple columns for non-exact match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following spreadsheet of products and rates against quantity ordered. Given what and how much customer ordered, I want to get the rate per unit. I have bit of flexibility - for example, I can repeat the product name on each row instead of "Merge & Center", if that makes writing formula easy.

Second column represents that the customer's order must be above that number to get the rate. For example:

- If customer orders 50 Bolts, then his rate would be $0.15 per Bolt.
- If customer orders 150 Bolts, then his rate would be $0.10 per Bolt.

One variable in this is that - management may decide to add another slab for discount. Say, for example, 5000 quantity order. Or another product and its discount slabs. So, I can't hard code the search range for any product.

I can't figure out how to do this lookup on multiple columns where one column has an exact match, while the other column has non-exact match. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am open to writing VBA code as well, if there is no suitable formula.

I looked at the [Excel Index-Match on multiple criteria with different match types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368885/excel-index-match-on-multiple-criteria-with-different-match-types), but the answer given to that question always returns value against quantity 0 regardless of quantity entered... even after I enter Bolt and Nut in all rows (instead of Merge & Center).

[image: My Data Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can also use this formula, when the `Product` column is merged and centered. Though it is recommended to avoid using the merged and centered cells.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J3</kbd>

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,$C$2:$C$15/
          ((LOOKUP(ROW($A$2:$A$15),ROW($A$2:$A$15)/
          ($A$2:$A$15<>""),$A$2:$A$15)=H3)*($B$2:$B$15<I3)),1)
```

---

Also, i would have used this below formula which does an approximate match instead of exact match, as it may happen the ordered quantities are different,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K3</kbd>

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$15,
  MATCH(1,$C$2:$C$15/
  ((LOOKUP(ROW($A$2:$A$15),ROW($A$2:$A$15)/($A$2:$A$15<>""),
  $A$2:$A$15)=H3)*($B$2:$B$15<I3)),1))
```

---

**Note:** Based on Excel Version, one may need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Using <kbd>SCAN( )</kbd>

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,$C$2:$C$15/
((SCAN("",$A$2:$A$15,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y)))=H3)*
($B$2:$B$15<I3)),1)
```

---

Comment: Other than the formula itself, what's the pros/cons of one (from cell J3) vs the other (cell K3)? Is one faster/accurate than the other?

Comment: @YogiWatcher both are accurate and the J3 will be bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

After bit of trial and error, I figured it out. Answer is similar to [Excel Index-Match on multiple criteria with different match types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368885/excel-index-match-on-multiple-criteria-with-different-match-types), except I needed to use function SMALL (number 15), and change <= to just <. I also needed to remove Merge & Center and repeat product name in all rows.

Here is the formula that worked for me, where cell H3 contained the product name and cell I3 contained the quantity.

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 7, C:C/((A$1:A$15=H3)*(B$1:B$15<I3)), 1)
```

Comment: I got it working, but can someone explain what the 3rd argument is: C:C/((A$1:A$15=H3)*(B$1:B$15<I3))

Comment: the third argument is **array** . First it checks whether the `Column A` matches with the value in `H3` and the `Column B` values is less than `I3` and then it divided the entire `Column C` by the returned values of the logical operations to return an array of values from `Col C` Also I have posted an answer you can use that as well

Answer (score 0):

### Exact and Approximate Matches

[image]

```
=LET(sData,A2:C15,spCol,1,sqCol,2,srCol,3,dData,E2:F7,dpCol,1,dqCol,2,
    sp,CHOOSECOLS(sData,spCol),sq,CHOOSECOLS(sData,sqCol),sr,CHOOSECOLS(sData,srCol),
    dp,CHOOSECOLS(dData,dpCol),dq,CHOOSECOLS(dData,dqCol),
    spu,UNIQUE(TOCOL(sp,1)),
    sput,XMATCH(spu,sp),
    spub,VSTACK(DROP(sput-1,1),ROWS(sp)),
    dr,MAP(dp,dq,LAMBDA(p,q,LET(
        spi,XMATCH(p,spu),
        st,INDEX(sput,spi,1),
        sb,INDEX(spub,spi,1),
        ss,SEQUENCE(sb-st+1,,st),
        sri,INDEX(sr,ss),
        sqi,INDEX(sq,ss),
        srVal,INDEX(sri,MATCH(q,sqi)),
        drVal,srVal*q,
    drVal))),
dr)
```

- To understand how it works, you can replace the bottom-most `dr` with any variable above the top-most `dr`.
- Similarly, you can replace the bottom-most `drVal` with any variable above the bottom-most `drVal`.
- Use a small sample so if a variable returns an array e.g. `ss`, instead of `drVal`, use the following:

  ```
  TEXTJOIN(", ",,ss)
  ```